# selenium setup with python for safari browser in mac

Tags: python, macos, selenium

The am using selenium with Python in mac and facing problem to run the test cases in Safari browser.

The command `sudo easy_install selenium` prints the following in the terminal:

> Searching for selenium
>       Best match: selenium 3.5.0
>       Processing selenium-3.5.0-py2.7.egg
>       selenium 3.5.0 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
>
> Using /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium-3.5.0-py2.7.egg
>       Processing dependencies for selenium
>       Finished processing dependencies for selenium

Now when I want to run a simple Python script to open a website, I use this code:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
driver = webdriver.Safari()
driver.get("https://www.google.co.in")
```

It shows this error in the terminal:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "a.py", line 5, in 
>           driver = webdriver.Safari()
>         File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium-3.5.0-py2.7.egg/selenium/webdriver/safari/webdriver.py", line 52, in **init**
>           desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
>         File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium-3.5.0-py2.7.egg/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 140, in **init**
>           self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
>         File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium-3.5.0-py2.7.egg/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 229, in start_session
>           response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
>         File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium-3.5.0-py2.7.egg/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 297, in execute
>           self.error_handler.check_response(response)
>         File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium-3.5.0-py2.7.egg/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
>           raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
>       selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Could not create a session: You must enable the 'Allow Remote Automation' option in Safari's Develop menu to control Safari via WebDriver

I am unable to find the exact problem.

Please help and thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you enable the the 'Allow Remote Automation' option in your mac?

Comment: yes I have enabled it.

Answer (score 1):

Open Safari and the in Develop menu check the option for `Allow Remote Execution`

[image: Enable Remote Automation]

And also run `safaridriver -p 5555` once in terminal, if it asks for allow permission then give it. This is only needed once. See the below article for more details

https://webkit.org/blog/6900/webdriver-support-in-safari-10/